# editor.wordWrap wraps text at weird locations

Tags: visual-studio-code, word-wrap

I am using vscode as a Latex editor, and I have noticed the UI, when word wrap is enabled, performs some pretty odd word wraps. For example, in the following sentence

```
Something is wrong here. And another sentence.
```

It has no problems in performing this type of wrapping (column:23):

```
Something is wrong here
. And another sentence.
```

While one would expect either of these to happen instead:

1) a one/two-character "forgiving" wrap

```
Something is wrong here.
And another sentence.
```

2) a "treat space as tokenizer" wrap

```
Something is wrong
here. And another
sentence.
```

Is there any way to tweak the current behavior?

Comment: I can't reproduce this - for me it wraps like your (2) example.  Are you using a monospace font?

Comment: I just tested this again, and I *think* they fixed it in the meantime.